# "By" Info on OpenSea

Tags: nft, opensea

When you visit a collection such as [Parallel Alpha](https://opensea.io/collection/parallelalpha) on OpenSea, you can see bellow the collection name "By Parallel", the creator account.

[image]

But when I see my own [test collection](https://opensea.io/collection/solarsystemnftest), I can't see the "By (My User)" link to my account. How to I add this info and link on OpenSea? So that my collection has the creator displayed like Parallel Alpha, and others?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You account needs to be verified first by OpenSea and your collection needs to have significant sales or interests before you will see a blue checkmark badge and a "by". You can check the requirements below:

https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/360063519133-What-is-a-verified-account-or-collection-

Comment: If you look at https://opensea.io/collection/mimicshhans , you will see they have the "By" info, but are not verified. So verification is something separate from what I'm asking... but I appreciate your reply.